# Bash, copiar archivos del servidor al disco local

Tags: bash

estoy intentando copiar algunos archivos que tengo en el servidor al disco local a traves del siguiente comando

```
    scp lab7@138.4.131.52:media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out adrian@adrianuser:~/adrian/Documents/
```

pero hasta ahora ejecutando dicho comando siempre he obtenido esta respuesta

```
      ssh: Could not resolve hostname adrianuser: Name or service not known lost connection
```

¿Como puedo copiarlos sin que me de este error?

---

tras la mayoria de los comentarios se descubrio el problema, y es que adrian es mi home por lo que el comando seria,
     scp lab7@138.4.131.52:media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out adrian@adrianuser:~/Documents/

Gracias por la atencion,
Un saludo

Comment: `adrianuser` es un server válido?

Comment: `scp user@host:/path/to/file .` si lo quieres copiar a la ruta que te encuentras actualmente, `scp user@host:/path/to/file /path/to/destination` si lo quieres copiar a otra carpeta

Comment: adrian@adrianuser son user@host de mi disco local (creo)

Comment: El usuario e ip ya estan modificadas

Comment: Que bueno, te me adelantaste ;) ¿probaste los comandos que te mencioné? deberían funcionar

Comment: scp lab7@138.4.131.52:media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out ~/adrian/Documents/  me salta con este error, No such file or directory. No se si estoy direccionando bien el disco local, perdonar por no ser conciso, no estoy muy familiarizado con este lenguaje

Comment: @KacosPro lo que quiero es copiarlo de una carpeta del servidor a una carpeta local

Comment: `media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out` es esa la ruta en el servidor?

Comment: si esa es mi ruta del servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que el problema relacionado con `No such file or directory.` esté en la ruta hacia el fichero que quieres copiar (origen):

```
media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out.
```

¿Existe el path `'media/...'` o te falta una barra al principio `'/media/...'`?

Con respecto al error de `Could not resolve hostname adrianuser`, ¿es posible que no tengas dado de alta ese host en tu máquina (ésto podrías comprobarlo haciendo un ping hacia ese host, `ping adrianuser`?

Comment: aun poniendo la barra scp lab7@138.4.131.52:/media/lab7/Disk1/blast_out/*e0001_ssRNA_blast.out ~/adrian/Documents/ tengo este error /home/adrian/adrian/Documents/: No such file or directory.  Ademas cuando compruebo si he dado de alta a mi host en mi maquina me sale esto,   ping: unknown host adrianuser

Comment: @AdriánP.L. tu problema es que adrian es tu home intentalo así ~/Documents

Comment: siiii, ya ha empezado a copiarse, muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda